# Store the Div id and checkbox value to an array(multi dimensional) Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store the div ID and the checked value into an array.

FIDDLE

Suppose I check `samsung` and `lenovo` from **brands** and `5gb` from **ram**, the array should be:

```
array[ ] = ["brand" => "samsung,lenovo" , "ram" => "5gb"]
```

HTML

```
 <div id="brand">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Samsung">Samsung<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Nikon">Nikon<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Lenovo">Lenovo<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Alcatel">Alcatel<br>
 </div>

<div id="ram">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="2 GB">2 GB<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="3 GB">3 GB<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="5 GB">5 GB<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="6 GB">6 GB<br>
</div>
```

Please note that the divs are dynamically grabbed from server. This is just an illustration, there are multiple divs and that it is not possible to know the `Id` of particular div. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is that a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('[type="button"]').click(function() {
  var results = [];
  $('div').each(function() {
    var vals = $(this).find(':checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');
    results[$(this).attr('id')] = vals;
  });
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Samsung">Samsung
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Nikon">Nikon
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Lenovo">Lenovo
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Alcatel">Alcatel
  <br>
</div>

<div id="ram">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="2 GB">2 GB
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="3 GB">3 GB
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="5 GB">5 GB
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="6 GB">6 GB
  <br>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Get Array" />
```

Comment: This leaves trailing commas. Better to just use an array and `.join(',')`.

Comment: @Alphabettt, it is working. you have to open the console to see the logged results

Comment: Thakyou again. But i am not able to alert the array.

Comment: @Alphabettt, can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle so I can be of better help?

Comment: @Alphabettt, you cannot use a for(i) loop in this case because the keys are not numbers but ids. You have to use a for in loop. http://jsfiddle.net/hn8t53cj/1/

Comment: Thakyou for all. Last question. How can I alert it as  suppose `brands: 'Samsung,Alcatel'` and `ram:'5gb'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = {};

// go through each checkbox
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    // initialize the array of values using the checkbox name/group
    values[this.name] = values[this.name] || [];

    if (this.checked)
    {
        // if the checkbox is checked, add it to the array of values
        values[this.name].push(this.value);
    }
});
```

This example assumes that your checkboxes have a `name` attribute, which they should. If they absolutely cannot have a `name` attribute (and, again, they really should), and you absolutely must use the `div` ID, you can use:

```
// if this.name (checkbox name/group) is unavailable, use closest div's ID
var name = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
```

Also, this example will construct a map of arrays, not a map of comma-separated values in strings. If you want strings, you can use `.join(',')` on the arrays.

Comment: Thankyou. I used `.join(', ')` still I am not able to output the array.

Answer (score 0):

This [little snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/wr3qzptu/) will create an array and update it based on the checkboxes. As per your question, it is multidimensional.

```
var arr = [];
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    $id = $this.parent().attr("id"),
    value = $this.val();
    if(typeof arr[$id] != "object"){
        arr[$id] = [];
    }
    if($this.is(":checked")){
        arr[$id].push(value);
    }else{
        var ai = arr[$id].indexOf(value);
        arr[$id].splice(ai, 1);
    }
});
```

If you need the brands and ram to be CSV (Comma Separated Values) then you can do as @Agop suggests and use `.join(',')` such as:

```
newArr['brand'] = arr['brand'].join(',');
```